# PowerBI Report to SharePoint 2013 Embedded Page

Tags: sharepoint-2013, powerbi-embedded

We have a PowerBI report embedded to a SharePoint 2013 web page. PowerBI provides you with the embedded code of your report to use on any web page.

Problem:
PowerBI decided to include the option of sharing your dashboard/report with the whole world using the Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn options. A simple single click your confidential report is on Twitter. To us this is a big security risk.

Findings:
I have used the F12 tools to hide the Social Media buttons and this works well while on F12 Tools. When I add this to the Script Editor in SharePoint page so it always applies, it doesn’t work. I thought a simple CSS would do the trick.

```
    glyphicon-share-twitter
    display:none
```

[[F12 Tools]](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6hRWbgcsfWINEM4cXVkNjB4RUk/view?usp=sharing)
[After F12 Tools - Twitter  hidden](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6hRWbgcsfWISjd2Nng0cER2LWM/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

It is still unsecure even without the share buttons.

> If you want to securely embed Power BI content you should use Power BI embedded or use the Power BI API's to embed and use the Power BI authentication.

Kasper de Jonge (Admin, Microsoft Power BI)
https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/16498078-disable-share-buttons